# Can std::begin work with array parameters and if so, how?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator, std

I have trouble using `std::begin()` and `std::end()` (from the `iterator` library) with c-style array parameters.

```
void SetOrigin(const double i_point[3]) {
  Vector v;
  std::copy(
    std::begin(i_point), 
    std::end(i_point), 
    v.begin());
  this->setOrigin(v);
}
```

This results in the following error with Visual Studio 2010 (and similar for end):

```
error C2784: '_Ty *std::begin(_Ty (&)[_Size])' : could not deduce template argument for '_Ty (&)[_Size]' from 'const double []'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(995) : see declaration of 'std::begin'
```

Changing the parameter to non-const gives same result.

Trying to specify the parameter as

```
...
std::begin<const double, 3>(i_point), 
std::end<const double, 3>(i_point),
...
```

Gives:

```
error C2664: '_Ty *std::begin<const double,3>(_Ty (&)[3])' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const double []' to 'const double (&)[3]'
```

Is it just not possible to use `std::begin` on array parameters because they decay to pointers?  Is there a trick to get around this or is it best just to not use the iterator functions on array parameters?

Comment: `i_point[3]` behaves like a flat pointer, rather than a real array, when used as a function parameter. Try the same with a local variable of array type, it should work.

Comment: `const double i_point[3]` this as a function parameter will decay to `const double *i_point`, you could use `const double (&i_point)[3]`

Comment: (for functions that want an array, just pass a pair of pointers)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, `std::begin` and `std::end` *can* work with parameters that are C style arrays.

The trick is in passing a parameter that's a C style array. When you specify a 1D array as a normal parameter to a normal function, its type is silently adjusted from "array of T" to "pointer to T". When you call that function, what gets passed isn't the array (as an array), but a pointer to the first element of the array.

It is, however, possible to pass an array by reference to a function template:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void function(T (&array)[N]) {
   // function body here
}
```

In *this* case, where you're passing an actual array (albeit, by reference) rather than a pointer, you can use `std::begin` and `std::end` perfectly well. For example:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T sum(T (&array)[N]) { 
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), T());
}
```

Now passing an array is trivial, such as:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

auto total = sum(array);
```

`std::begin` and `std::end` themselves are (or at least can be) implemented similarly to `sum`--the array is passed by reference, so they can look something like this:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
T *begin(T (&array)[N]) { 
    return array; 
}

template <class T, size_t N>
T *end(T (&array)[N]) {
    return array + N;
}
```

Note that although these were added to the standard more recently, they don't require any particularly tricky use of templates, so the implementation above should work fine with a plain old C++98 compiler (and, if memory serves, even with pre-standard compilers such as VC++ 6).

Answer (score 4):

First off, note that the parameter declaration `const double i_point[3]` is absolutely equivalent to `const double* i_point`. That is, the function takes any pointer to `double const` independent of the number of elements pointed to. As a result, it doesn't know the size and `std::begin()` and `std::end()` can't deduce the size (well, `std::begin()` doesn't really need to deduce the size anyway).

If you really want to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` you need to pass an array with three element or a reference to such a beast. Since you cannot pass arrays by value, your best bet is to pass it by reference:

```
void SetOrigin(double const (&i_point)[3]) {
    // ...
}
```

This function only accepts arrays with exactly three elements as arguments: You cannot pass a pointer to three `double`s or a part of a bigger array. In return, you can now use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void SetOrigin(const double i_point[3])
```

is as same as

```
void SetOrigin(const double i_point[])
```

or

```
void SetOrigin(const double *i_point)
```

So, `std::begin` and `std::end` can not accept it. In C++ you can not pass an array but as a pointer or reference. If it's a pointer then it doesn't carry any information of passed array.

Your alternatives are `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: @chris: Totally forgotten that. I've just mentioned that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at std::array?

It works better with other STL components

Comment: Precision is everything: `std::array` (note the `a` vs. `A`) ;-)

Comment: @DietmarKühl Wouldn't that be more a question of accuracy than precision?

Comment: Indeed I have, but simply want an interface for someone who wants to call my function with a c-style array as the argument.  I have another version that accepts `std::array`.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum: touché! English isn't my native language and I'm barely capable of expressing myself.

Answer (score 0):

While not directly answering your question (it has already been answered sufficiently by [M M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059635/529761) and [Dietmar Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20059695/529761)), you appear to want to initialize some `std::vector` in this function.  That said, why not just have:

```
std::vector v;
std::copy(std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::back_inserter(v));
// or std::copy(x, x + 3, std::back_inserter(v));
```

Instead of a function call to your function that is trying to do this?

Alternatively, you could write you function like this:

```
template<typename RandomIterator>
void SetOrigin(RandomIterator start, RandomIterator end)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::copy(start, end, std::back_inserter(v));
    SetOrigin(v);
}
```

and then call it using:

```
double xyz[3];
SetOrigin(std::begin(xyz), std::end(xyz));
```

Comment: In this case I am not attempting what you suspect, but I see your point if I were.